# google sheet ( name sheet )

Tags: arrays, import, google-sheets-formula, formula, google-query-language

I need help, I have daily reservations every day in Sheet until the end of the month (updating the length of the month on the days)

I want to deport all days in a separate sheet, provided that the sheet number is written in the collection table

Together automatic update

Daily bookings link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-5T8icAKfveyDWeeyLf1bguDwGYP9mSONuUzYohbOAk/edit?usp=sharing

Booking aggregation link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-NDjvf0fO4FjLcv8Mj-fR7bY_P2-3NZE1mSFIadP9U8/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you guys

Comment: I want to combine all the data from these sheets into one but I also wanted to have a column that can tell me from which sheet I am getting my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY({
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1-5T8icAKfveyDWeeyLf1bguDwGYP9mSONuUzYohbOAk", "1!G11:I"), "select Col1,Col2,Col3,'1' label '1'''");
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1-5T8icAKfveyDWeeyLf1bguDwGYP9mSONuUzYohbOAk", "2!G11:I"), "select Col1,Col2,Col3,'2' label '2'''");
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1-5T8icAKfveyDWeeyLf1bguDwGYP9mSONuUzYohbOAk", "3!G11:I"), "select Col1,Col2,Col3,'3' label '3'''");
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1-5T8icAKfveyDWeeyLf1bguDwGYP9mSONuUzYohbOAk", "4!G11:I"), "select Col1,Col2,Col3,'4' label '4'''");
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1-5T8icAKfveyDWeeyLf1bguDwGYP9mSONuUzYohbOAk", "5!G11:I"), "select Col1,Col2,Col3,'5' label '5'''");
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1-5T8icAKfveyDWeeyLf1bguDwGYP9mSONuUzYohbOAk", "6!G11:I"), "select Col1,Col2,Col3,'6' label '6'''")},
 "where Col3 is not null", )
```

[image]